# AS3: Add multiple childs next to eachother

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem. When I loop this code, my intensions was that it would add 6 pictures after eachother. However; it did not work. Can anyone please help?

```
var riktige:RRR = new RRR();

var r:int = 6;
var xPos:uint = 50;
var yPos:uint = 140;

for(var i:int=0; i<6; i++) {
   addChild(riktige);
   riktige.x = xPos;
   riktige.y = yPos;
   xPos += 40;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only create one instance of `RRR` while you say you need six. Put `riktige=new RRR();` in the for loop to resolve.

```
for(var i:int=0; i<6; i++) {
   riktige=new RRR();
   addChild(riktige);
   riktige.x = xPos;
   riktige.y = yPos;
   xPos += 40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see this has already been answered but you will one day want to get those off the stage or work with them in some way so I think you should store references to each one to work with later like so...

```
var riktigeRef:Array = new Array();

for(var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    riktigeRef.push(new RRR());
    riktigeRef[riktigeRef.length - 1].x = xPos;
    riktigeRef[riktigeRef.length - 1].y = yPos;
    addChild(riktigeRef[riktigeRef.length - 1]);
    xPos += 40;
}
```

or use this loop if you never plan to use this loop again later on.

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    riktigeRef[i] = new RRR();
    riktigeRef[i].x = xPos;
    riktigeRef[i].y = yPos;
    addChild(riktigeRef[i]);
    xPos += 40;
}
```

when you need to you can cycle through that array to remove them from the stage or work with individual instances rather then work with the children on the stage which could take longer if you add a lot more stuff.